# Plone ldap add on installation issue

Tags: ldap, plone, buildout

I am trying to get ldap authentication to work on Plone version 4.2. I have hammered at the issue for several hours without results. I have even tried these steps:

1. Install python-ldap 2.6 (C:\Python26)
2. Install Plone 4.2 with the installer (D:\Plone)
3. Edit buildout.cfg with plone.app.ldap in the EGG and ZCML section
4. Create a new folder called python_ldap-2.3.12-py2.6.egg in D:\Plone\buildout-cache\eggs\
5. Copy C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\python_ldap-2.3.12-py2.6.egg-info to D:\Plone\buildout-cache\eggs\python_ldap-2.3.12-py2.6.egg\ and rename to EGG-INFO
6. Also copy the ldap folder in C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\ to D:\Plone\buildout-cache\eggs\python_ldap-2.3.12-py2.6.egg\
7. Also copy the file ldapurl.py to C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\ to D:\Plone\buildout-cache\eggs\python_ldap-2.3.12-py2.6.egg\
8. Next copy: 
   folder: C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\python_ldap-2.3.12-py2.6.egg-info 
   folder: C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\ldap 
   to D:\Plone\python\Lib\site-packages
9. Start commandbox and run bin\buildout
10. Start Plone, log in as admin and go to the extra products section. Here you will find the LDAP product. Install it and enter you LDAP details.

None of that really helped. When i try bin/buildout, I get the following message:

```
Installing instance.
Getting distribution for 'dataflake.fakeldap'.
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...

Installed /tmp/easy_install-oISsVG/dataflake.fakeldap-1.0/setuptools_git-0.4.2-py2.6.egg
Got dataflake.fakeldap 1.0.
Generated script '/usr/local/Plone/zinstance/bin/instance'.
Installing zopepy.
Generated interpreter '/usr/local/Plone/zinstance/bin/zopepy'.
Installing zopeskel.
Generated script '/usr/local/Plone/zinstance/bin/zopeskel'.
Generated script '/usr/local/Plone/zinstance/bin/paster'.
Updating backup.
Updating chown.
chown: Running 
echo Dummy references to force this to execute after referenced parts
echo /usr/local/Plone/zinstance/var/backups sudo -u plone
chmod 600 .installed.cfg
find /usr/local/Plone/zinstance/var -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
chmod 744 /usr/local/Plone/zinstance/bin/*
Dummy references to force this to execute after referenced parts
/usr/local/Plone/zinstance/var/backups sudo -u plone
Updating repozo.
Updating unifiedinstaller.
*************** PICKED VERSIONS ****************
[versions]
Products.LDAPMultiPlugins = 1.14
Products.LDAPUserFolder = 2.23
Products.PloneLDAP = 1.1
collective.sendaspdf = 2.6
dataflake.fakeldap = 1.0
jquery.pyproxy = 0.4.1
plone.app.ldap = 1.2.8

*************** /PICKED VERSIONS ***************
```

When I try bin/buildout, it says daemon process started and gives an id but when i try localhost:8080, it says "Problem loading page" and the page does not load. I tried bin/instance fg to display the errors and i following  message.

```
bin/instance fg
2012-07-24 08:53:18 INFO ZServer HTTP server started at Tue Jul 24 08:53:18 2012
        Hostname: 0.0.0.0
        Port: 8080
2012-07-24 08:53:18 INFO Zope Set effective user to "plone"
2012-07-24 08:53:19 WARNING SecurityInfo Conflicting security declarations for "setText"
2012-07-24 08:53:19 WARNING SecurityInfo Class "ATTopic" had conflicting security declarations
2012-07-24 08:53:19 ERROR Application Could not import Products.LDAPMultiPlugins
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.6.egg/OFS/Application.py", line 606, in import_product
    product=__import__(pname, global_dict, global_dict, silly)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.LDAPMultiPlugins-1.14-py2.6.egg/Products/LDAPMultiPlugins/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from Products.LDAPMultiPlugins.LDAPMultiPlugin import addLDAPMultiPluginForm
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.LDAPMultiPlugins-1.14-py2.6.egg/Products/LDAPMultiPlugins/LDAPMultiPlugin.py", line 29, in <module>
    from Products.LDAPUserFolder import manage_addLDAPUserFolder
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.LDAPUserFolder-2.23-py2.6.egg/Products/LDAPUserFolder/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from Products.LDAPUserFolder.LDAPUserFolder import LDAPUserFolder
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.LDAPUserFolder-2.23-py2.6.egg/Products/LDAPUserFolder/LDAPUserFolder.py", line 52, in <module>
    from Products.LDAPUserFolder.LDAPDelegate import filter_format
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.LDAPUserFolder-2.23-py2.6.egg/Products/LDAPUserFolder/LDAPDelegate.py", line 19, in <module>
    import ldap
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/python_ldap-2.3.12-py2.6.egg/ldap/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from _ldap import *
ImportError: No module named _ldap
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.6.egg/Zope2/Startup/run.py", line 76, in <module>
    run()
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.6.egg/Zope2/Startup/run.py", line 22, in run
    starter.prepare()
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.6.egg/Zope2/Startup/__init__.py", line 86, in prepare
    self.startZope()
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.6.egg/Zope2/Startup/__init__.py", line 259, in startZope
    Zope2.startup()
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.6.egg/Zope2/__init__.py", line 47, in startup
    _startup()
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.6.egg/Zope2/App/startup.py", line 67, in startup
    OFS.Application.import_products()
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.6.egg/OFS/Application.py", line 583, in import_products
    import_product(product_dir, product_name, raise_exc=debug_mode)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.6.egg/OFS/Application.py", line 606, in import_product
    product=__import__(pname, global_dict, global_dict, silly)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.LDAPMultiPlugins-1.14-py2.6.egg/Products/LDAPMultiPlugins/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from Products.LDAPMultiPlugins.LDAPMultiPlugin import addLDAPMultiPluginForm
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.LDAPMultiPlugins-1.14-py2.6.egg/Products/LDAPMultiPlugins/LDAPMultiPlugin.py", line 29, in <module>
    from Products.LDAPUserFolder import manage_addLDAPUserFolder
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.LDAPUserFolder-2.23-py2.6.egg/Products/LDAPUserFolder/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from Products.LDAPUserFolder.LDAPUserFolder import LDAPUserFolder
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.LDAPUserFolder-2.23-py2.6.egg/Products/LDAPUserFolder/LDAPUserFolder.py", line 52, in <module>
    from Products.LDAPUserFolder.LDAPDelegate import filter_format
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.LDAPUserFolder-2.23-py2.6.egg/Products/LDAPUserFolder/LDAPDelegate.py", line 19, in <module>
    import ldap
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/python_ldap-2.3.12-py2.6.egg/ldap/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from _ldap import *
ImportError: No module named _ldap
```

What am i doing wrong? Help wil be deeply appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buildout ran successfully, there were no problems there. Some of the packages you picked were not pinned, so your buildout reported what versions it choose for you.

Your server itself is not indeed running because the Python LDAP egg you installed seems to be incorrectly installed. The `buildout-cache/eggs/python_ldap-2.3.12-py2.6.egg/ldap/_ldap.so` library file is missing.

Remove the whole egg (`rm -rf buildout-cache-eggs/python_ldap-2.3.12-py2.6.egg`) make sure you have the OpenLDAP 2.x library and headers installed on your system (on Ubuntu and Debian the `libldap2-dev` should be enough). Then re-run buildout to reinstall the egg.

Alternatively, you could try and install the system `python-ldap` package (remove the egg) and see if buildout picks that up instead.

Comment: I updated the question by adding the errors shown after executing the bin/instance fg command. What does that suggest? Thank you

Comment: Executed the rm -rf buildout-cache-eggs/python_ldap-2.3.12-py2.6.egg command, installed OpenLDAP 2 libraries and ran bin/buildout again. It ran without errors, however I did not see it install python-ldap again. In fact it gave me the same results as i mentioned in the question. I tried running the bin/instance fg again and it gave me the same results.

Comment: Tried that too. Same problem :(. It's been a frustrating experience.

Comment: Sorry this is so frustrating! I have no idea why your python-ldap installation is failing in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install 2 libs:

```
sudo apt-get install libldap2-dev

sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev
```

Hope that will help.